# Balance tabular columns automatically?

Tags: tables, tabularx

How to balance the columns of such declaration:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
  >{\hsize=0.4\hsize}X% 10% of 4\hsize
  >{\hsize=1.6\hsize}X% 30% of 4\hsize
  >{\hsize=0.4\hsize}X% 10% of 4\hsize
  >{\hsize=1.6\hsize}X% 30% of 4\hsize
  }
\end{tabularx}
```

Obviously the values `0.4` and `1.6` have to be adjusted automatically at build time...

Example:

```
     .--------- Same width ---------------.
     |                                    |
<----+--->                            <---+---->    
┌────────┬────────────────────────────┬────────┬───────────────────────────┐
│ A      │ B                          │ A      │ B                         │
├────────┼────────────────────────────┼────────┼───────────────────────────┤
│ 132132 │ Sed rutrum elit quis neque │ 42     │ Cras porta                │
└────────┴────────────────────────────┴────────┴───────────────────────────┘
         <------------+--------------->        <-------------+------------->
                      |                                      |
                      '------------- Same width -------------'
```

Where the odd column have size `A` and the even ones a size `B`? With this I guarantee that column 1 and 3 have always the same size, and column 2 and 4 are equally distributed in space.

In other words, the min width of the columns are determined as follow:

```
min_widths[0] = min_widths[2] = max(map(width, columns[0] + columns[2]))
min_widths[1] = min_widths[3] = max(map(width, columns[1] + columns[3]))
```

Then everything is stretch to fit in the `\linewidth`:

```
if sum(min_widths) > \linewidth: 
    % Attempts to wrap some text and reduce the column sizes
else: 
    widths = map(lambda x: x * (\linewidth / sum(min_widths), min_widths)
```

Good parameters for such feature would be:

```
- Column alignment: left, center, right, raggedleft, raggedright
- Maximum width: e.g. 10em
- Minimum width: e.g. 0em
- Desired width ratio: 1
- Automatic wrapping: yes, no
```

Comment: It is not very clear (to me) , what you like to have ... but see if you looking for something like this: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{2}{>{\hsize=0.4\hsize}X 
                                  >{\hsize=1.6\hsize}X}
                            }
    \hline
xxx xxx  & xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx & xxx xxx  & xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}`

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: Why do you want to use tabularx for this? You could simply set the column type to `p{some-calculated-width}`.

Comment: Because the table should have the width `\linewidth`

Comment: You might prefer tabulary to tabularx

Comment: The `X` column type is nothing but a `p`-type column for which LaTeX takes on the job of calculating the absolute width of the column should be, given information about the overall width of the `tabularx` environment, the number of `X`-type columns, and the number and width of any other columns. Since `X` columns, like `p` columns, are set up to allow automatic line breaking, it's not clear to me if there's enough information contained in the setup you've described to perform the required relative and absolute width calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.25a). In that environment, you have a key `columns-width=auto` which requires all the columns to have the same width, except the `X` columns (which are similar to the `X` columns of `tabularx`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lXlX}[columns-width=auto,hvlines]
A & B & A & B \\
132132 & Sed rutrum elit quis neque & 42 & Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna
fringilla ultrices. 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 3):

*EDIT 20190807* At the end of the answer, I have included the code I recommend, an amalgamation of Zarko’s and my answer.

You may have a `tabular` to use the whole `linewidth` by calculating the width of `p{}`-columns as fractions of the `linewidth`. Just ensure that the total number of column widths accumulate to the `linewidth`. You have to subtract the correct number of `tabcolsep`s, which is two per column (total eight for four columns). If you have vertical rules, you also have to subtract the correct numbers of `arrayrulewidth`s.

I have ‘improved’ the previous example. If you look at the definition of an `A`-column, it now reads:

```
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr(1\textwidth)*25/100/2-1.5\tabcolsep\relax}}
```

1. If you prefer centred or right aligned columns, you change `\RaggedRight` to `\Centering` or `\RaggedLeft`.
2. If you need a tabular where the total width is less than the full `linewidth`, you change `(1\linewidth)` to the correct fraction. For example, if you need a tabular 80 per cent of the `linewidth`, you use `(0.8\linewidth)`.
3. The formula `25/100/2` is the relative width of the `A`-column, here 25%. This number is meant to be set so that the total of the `newcolumntype` is 100. Therefore, the `B`-column use `75/100`. The last digit is the number of `A`-or `B`-columns.
4. If you remove the left and right side bearings, (`@{}`), the number of `tabcolsep`s to subtract will be two less than the total number of `tabcolsept`s. If you have four columns, you have to subtract six, if you have six columns, you have so subtract ten, *etc*. The formula will be `-(2\tabcolsep-(\tabcolsep/<no. col.type>))`. If you have three `A`-columns, you have to subtract `-(2\tabcolsep-(\tabcolsep/3))`.
5. If you use vertical rules, you have to distribute the number of `arrayruleswidth` correctly, too. I leave it to you as an exercise to do that.

Above, I have assumed you will use equal number of each column types (ABAB, ABBA, ABBBAA *etc*.). In an automated calculation you have to take into consideration that the number of column types not necessarily will be the same number (you may have ABBAA, ABABA, *etc*.). So you will easily end up with a very complicated package. Probably it is better to use a calculator, or pen and paper, to fix the column width. Obviously, it is much faster than program it in LaTeX.

**NB!** *I emphasise that `tabularx` and `tabulary` already do all the maths for you. However, have a look at section 4.3 in the `tabularx`-manual.*

Below I have enclosed code for a tabular with six columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{A}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr(1\textwidth)*25/100/3-(2\tabcolsep-(\tabcolsep/3))\relax}}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr(1\textwidth)*75/100/3-(2\tabcolsep-(\tabcolsep/3))\relax}}
\usepackage{showframe}

\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{.4pt}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}

\begin{document}
{\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ABABBA@{}}

\toprule
A   &    B  &   A   &   B &   A   &   B\\
\midrule
Short left alig\-ned column & Wide centered column, which has lots of text & Short left alig\-ned column & Wide centered column, which has lots of text  & Wide centered column, which has lots of text & Short left alig\-ned column  \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}%
}
\end{document}
```

**Recommended example code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\small\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=0.4\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{E}{>{\small\Centering\arraybackslash\hsize=1.6\hsize}X}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}DEDEED@{}}
\toprule
D   &    E  &   D   &   E  &   E   &   D\\
\midrule
Short left alig\-ned column & Wide centered column, which has lots of text & Short left alig\-ned column & Wide centered column, which has lots of text  & Wide centered column, which has lots of text & Short left alig\-ned column  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the question, tables should have a width equal to the width of the text. So, I don't see any advantages (maybe due to my vacation?) why *not* to use `tabularx` as I suggested in my comment below question:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{2}{>{\hsize=0.4\hsize}X| >{\hsize=1.6\hsize}X|} } 
    \hline 
xxx xxx & xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx 
    & xxx xxx & xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx\\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Four column}
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{3}{>{\hsize=0.4\hsize}X| >{\hsize=1.6\hsize}X|} }
    \hline 
xxx xxx & xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx 
    & xxx xxx & xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx 
        & xxx xxx & xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx\\
    \hline 
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Sixt column}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Comment: And if you have to use `multicolumn` (and `multirow`?), section 4.3 in the tabularx-manual has a warning. However, I have, as far as I can remember, never run into any issues. I were the OP, I would have chosen to use tabularx as you describe, but defining new columntypes (as I have done).

Comment: @Sveinung, with the recent `multirow` you can use `=` option and with it preserve column specification, with `\multicolumn` you should be aware how the column widths are determined (about this you can find  many answers on this site)

Comment: @Sveinung, thank you very much for editing of my answer. Now MWE is complete and language improved!

Comment: In your case you specified the size of each columns. I do want to LaTeX to determine automatically the width of the columns based on the content. The table with the four columns `xxxx|xxxxxxxx|x|xxxx|` will have the widths `4, 8, 4, 8` so the first column width is the maximum width of the column 1 and 3: `min(4, 1)=4`

Comment: @nowox It is difficult to understand what you try to archive. Is it so that the width of column 1 shall be calculated, and column 3 shall have the same width? And then the rest of available space between the margins shall be distributed evenly on column 2 and 4? I.e. there is not a predetermined fixed ratio between A--type and B-type column?

Comment: @nowox, well, than you should wait on some wizard who will provide such a solution :-(. Good luck!